# Script runs on Linux machine startup, retry if fails

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks

I want to set up a script that runs after my Linux starts up, and keep retrying (at an interval, say 1 minute) if fails. How do I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be distro/version specific - or more precisely based on what init system you use - without knowing this, its pretty hard to answer. Its much more elegant in upstart or systemd

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup) for how to run a script on startup. To keep retrying, write a wrapper for your script which determines if the script failed or not, and if it did, wait 1 minute then try again. It really depends what language you are writing in, so if you want more help, please provide more details.

You can create a loop with a bash script using [these instructions](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html).

```
i="0"

while [ $i -ne 1 ]
do

# Run your script here
# if script was successful, set $i to 1

sleep 60
done
```

Comment: And within the `while` loop you can use `$?` to ask for the return status of your script, just after the line that runs it.